# How to convert character matrix to numeric, keeping first column as row name: R

Tags: r, matrix, numeric

I have this matrix below and the apply loop changes the row names to numbers.

This is matrix:

```
             treatmenta treatmentb
John Smith   NA         " 2"      
John Doe     "16"       "11"      
Mary Johnson " 3"       " 1"
```

and this code `as.matrix(apply(y, 2, as.numeric))`

results is this but i want the row names to be people names

```
     treatmenta treatmentb
[1,]         NA          2
[2,]         16         11
[3,]          3          1
```

Converting to data.table also does not work.  How do I do this?

Here is code to reproduce data:

```
name <- c("John Smith", "John Doe", "Mary Johnson")
treatmenta <- c("NA", "16", "3")
treatmentb <- c("2", "11", "1")
y <- data.frame(name, treatmenta, treatmentb)
rownames(y) <- y[,1]
y[,1] <- NULL
```

Comment: Based on the reproducible data showed, it is a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`.  `y[] <- lapply(y, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: Use data frames instead. Any reason why it should be a matrix? You can also `cbind` the names column separately if you have to.

Comment: when you use the transpose t() from the reshape package it takes data frames and makes them matrices.  I added fastest way to produce the data which is a data frame.  Sorry about that but good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
y <- `dimnames<-`(`dim<-`(as.numeric(y), dim(y)), dimnames(y))
y
#              treatmenta treatmentb
#John Smith           NA          2
#John Doe             16         11
#Mary Johnson          3          1
```

---

Or a compact option is

```
class(y) <- "numeric"
```

#### data

```
y <- structure(c(NA, "16", " 3", " 2", "11", " 1"), .Dim = c(3L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("John Smith", "John Doe", "Mary Johnson"
), c("treatmenta", "treatmentb")))
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to change to numeric.  maybe i am missing something but when i try to add `y[1,2] + y[2,2]` i get
`Error in y[1, 2] + y[2, 2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @BrianWiley You need to assign it to `y` i.e. `y <- ` and then do `y[1,2] + y[2,2]
#[1] 13`

Comment: ok that works thank.  the compact option does not i get error `Error in class(y) <- "numeric" : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: @BrianWiley  I assumed that you have a `matrix` as you mentioned in the post.  If you use the data from my post, it should work fine.  Looks like you have a new code about how you created the data.  The dataset is a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`

Answer (score 0):

You are going from a more general dataform (dataframes) to matrixes (vectors with dim attribute). During this as.matrix or any method from the base that converts your data to matrix will eventually call vector(x) which is generic function setting all your variables to charactor or will set everything to numeric but the name column to NAs (depending on how you call as.matrix).

Having said that, if for some reason you still have to use matrix form then use this for better readability:

```
treatmenta <- c("1", "16", "3")
treatmentb <- c("2", "11", "1")
y[,1] <- as.matrix(sapply(treatmenta, as.numeric))
y[,2] <- as.matrix(sapply(treatmentb, as.numeric))
#now they are not factors. 
#> class(y)
#[1] "matrix"

name <- c("John Smith", "John Doe", "Mary Johnson")
row.names(y) <- name
# treatmenta treatmentb
# John Smith            1          2
# John Doe             16         11
# Mary Johnson          3          1
```

Comment: Yes i saw this apply in another post.  This gives me the  below:      `treatmenta treatmentb
[1,]         NA          2
[2,]         16         11
[3,]          3          1`  it removes the rownames.

Comment: just eddited the answer. take another look. remoced the NA but won't be a problem if it has NA values. @BrianWiley

Comment: right, i am referring to just an example data set if you are transposing, using the t(), which converts your data from numeric to character.  So if we have a huge data set we are not going to create like this.  It's already going to transposed to a character matrix.  You  have to convert it back to numeric.

Comment: you can't have the row names inside your matrix. as.matrix calls vector(x) which is a general atomic method- converts everything to one type or the other. use `rownames()` to separately have the names added in the end. @BrianWiley